# How to call different divs in same drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down menu having different options which are hard coded. After that, there is another drop down menu which is disabled when no option from first drop down is selected and when we select any option it is enabled and shows some values.
I want to show different options in second drop down based on the value selected in first drop down i.e. in the same second drop down menu. I have created different divs for every value (having drop downs) selected in first. So i want to call that particular div for every value selected. Here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function check(elem) {
            
    document.getElementById('mySelect1').disabled = !elem.selectedIndex;
}
    </script>
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);" >
<option>Select an Option</option>
<option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="name" >Names</option>
  <option value="course" >Courses</option>
 </select>
 <select id="mySelect1" disabled="disabled" >
    <?php
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT names FROM table ";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    echo "<option  value=' " . $row['Sno'] ."'>" . $row['names'] ."</option>";
    } 
?>
</select>
<select id="mySelect1" disabled="disabled" >
    <?php
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT courses FROM table ";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    echo "<option  value=' " . $row['Sno'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] ."</option>";
    } 
?>
</select>
```

e.g. When i select name in first drop down menu, it shows me all the names from database in second div and when i select courses it shows me all the courses in the same drop down

Comment: This isn't an answer. just an observation: you should avoid using `mysql_` as it is depreciated as of 5.5.x, and element ids must be unique (you have used `mySelect1` twice).

Comment: May I know why unaccept?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: May I know why unupvote?

Comment: no i haven't done this

Comment: Ok, I see. By the way, new update because I think I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not give the same id to more than one element.

**Here is working example** of how you can do what you want

```js
function check(elem) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.second').forEach(function(e) {
    e.disabled = true;
  });

  if (elem.value !== "none" && elem.value !== "all") {
    document.getElementById(elem.value).disabled = false;
  } else if (elem.value === "all") {
    document.querySelectorAll('.second').forEach(function(e) {
      e.disabled = false;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);">
  <option value="none">Select an Option</option>
  <option value="all">Select All</option>
  <option value="names">Names</option>
  <option value="courses">Courses</option>
</select>
<select id="names" class="second" disabled="disabled">
  <option value='John'>John</option>
  <option value='Jacob'>Jacob</option>
  <option value='Victoria'>Victoria</option>
  <option value='Maurice'>Maurice</option>
</select>
<select id="courses" class="second" disabled="disabled">
  <option value='Course1'>Course 1</option>
  <option value='Course2'>Course 2</option>
  <option value='Course3'>Course 3</option>
  <option value='Course4'>Course 4</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

If you want it in one select instead of two then two select fields in html are unnecessary

**Here is a working solution** for one select with different options depending on first select value.

```js
function check(elem) {
  document.getElementById('select2').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('select2').value = "";
  document.querySelectorAll('#select2 option').forEach(function(e) {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  });

  if (elem.value === "none") {
    document.getElementById('select2').disabled = true;
  }
  if (elem.value !== "all") {
    document.querySelectorAll('#select2 option.' + elem.value).forEach(function(e) {
      e.style.display = 'initial';
    });
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('#select2 option').forEach(function(e) {
      if (e.value !== "") {
        e.style.display = 'initial';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onChange="check(this);">
  <option value="none">Select an Option</option>
  <option value="all">Select All</option>
  <option value="name">Names</option>
  <option value="course">Courses</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" disabled="disabled">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option class="name" value='John'>John</option>
  <option class="name" value='Jacob'>Jacob</option>
  <option class="name" value='Victoria'>Victoria</option>
  <option class="name" value='Maurice'>Maurice</option>
  <!-- Here instead of html you can insert your php -->
  <option class="course" value='Course1'>Course 1</option>
  <option class="course" value='Course2'>Course 2</option>
  <option class="course" value='Course3'>Course 3</option>
  <option class="course" value='Course4'>Course 4</option>
  <!-- Here instead of html you can insert your php -->
</select>
```

**EDIT2**

**Here is a solution** for a select with names and courses and two selects after the first one.

```js
function check(elem) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.second').forEach(function(e) {
    e.style.display = "none";
  });
  
  if (elem.value === "all") {
    document.getElementById("names").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("courses").style.display = "initial";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);">
  <option value="none">Select an Option</option>
  <option value="all">Select All</option>
  <option value='John'>John</option>
  <option value='Jacob'>Jacob</option>
  <option value='Victoria'>Victoria</option>
  <option value='Maurice'>Maurice</option>
  <option value='Course1'>Course 1</option>
  <option value='Course2'>Course 2</option>
  <option value='Course3'>Course 3</option>
  <option value='Course4'>Course 4</option>
</select>
<select id="names" class="second" style="display: none;">
  <option value='John'>John</option>
  <option value='Jacob'>Jacob</option>
  <option value='Victoria'>Victoria</option>
  <option value='Maurice'>Maurice</option>
</select>
<select id="courses" class="second" style="display: none;">
  <option value='Course1'>Course 1</option>
  <option value='Course2'>Course 2</option>
  <option value='Course3'>Course 3</option>
  <option value='Course4'>Course 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not the solution for my problem

Comment: I want to show both the rows of names and courses in one drop down & when I select "select all" option there appears many drop downs one for every option. Can u help me with this?